# Visual studio 2015 waiting for localhost after first load for debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, localhost

I have been struggling with debugging on Visual studio 2015 Community Update 1 and 2. After first debug session everything works correctly. But when I make changes during the debug and I refresh the website, it start waiting on localhost forever. This also happens if I stop debugging, make changes and then launch debug session again. This happens 95% of the time. I have searched stackoverflow and googled for similiar problems and none of the answer others has proposed has not fixed this problem. Only what works is to restart VS again after first debug.

What I have tried so far:

1. Uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 and installed back.
2. Cleaned Temp folder(that what is used with IIS Express)
3. Reinstalled IIS 10
4. Launched VS as administator-
5. ...... Created whole new solution with 3 projects and copy pasted all code to new solution - hoping this could fix any path problems.
6. Created new TFS project and linked there
7. Disabled Firewall temporarily
8. Just released Update 2 for VS 2015 Community didn't fix also.
9. Cleared symblos also loaded symbols from microsoft servers.
10. Disabled Browser Link

I'm running out of patience and ideas how to fix this annoying problem.
My guess is something goes wrong after first load of files and then when VS try to copy files back to temporary folder, it can't or something stops working. Anyone got ideas?

Comment: I resolve this issue by installing vs 2017 and then vs 2015 began to work

Answer (score 3):

Here are new things for you to try, I believe one of them will solve ur issue. I am listing from most I believed to least:

- Try to create new app pool and assign your website to it. Make sure
  the user authentication for the new app pool is provided correctly.
- Set the connection timeout to something reasonable like 15 seconds in
  the web.config.
- Try using local IP address instead localhost Disable
  all the antivirus programs in addition to firewalls, if you are
  using. Check for the blocked ports on firewall and change the dynamic
  ports of application if any to fixed trustable ports.
- Someone says on the internet:"the problem might be that downloading files from torrent and your database is on a different server"
- Someone on internet also says: "I deleted the .suo file and this fixed the issue."

This website might help also: http://dustyreagan.com/localhost-doesnt-work-cant-debug-your/

EDIT:
Please check the solutions on this websites: https://marcclifton.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/page-not-rendering-with-iis-express-in-firefox-or-chrome-waiting-for-localhost/

http://codetunnel.io/how-to-debug-your-aspnet-projects-running-under-iis/

Comment: None of these worked. But I actually managed to get it worked with other browsers than Chrome. I'm going to try other browsers and see if this is the case that chrome is no working properly.

Comment: Added a new link for you to check.. @JonKoivula

Comment: In addition, also please restart IIS when you make some changes before trying

Comment: This problem seems random. It is now working most of the time again. There was a time that it was not working after making changes to HTML and then I refreshed page in Chrome, but in IE it refreshed. And sometimes it couldn't also in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to:

```
taskkill /f /im:iisexpress.exe
rmdir /s /q [path to your solution]\bin
rmdir /s /q [path to your solution]\obj
taskkill /f /im:conhost.exe
```

I've that in a wee batch file that I run before trying to deploy / debug, particularly when I'm switching between Debug and Release modes.  Basically, clearing out the objects and killing off the iis express and console host give you a fresh start.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by the SignalR performance counters (if you use SignalR). If you install them manually, the waiting for local host disappears.

A detailed description on how to install the SignalR performance counters can be found on the Microsoft site:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#perfcounters